# Divide the string with a dot in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, delimiter

How can I divide a string with dots as delimiters in Groovy?

If I have a string like `"22112018"`, how do I convert it to `"22.11.2018"`?

**EDIT:**

I wasn't really sure how to formulate the question. I wanted to 'split' the string but `split()` method doesn't do what I need (doesn't mean the same).

This answer in comments (by @ernest_k) was good enough for what I needed:

```
text = "22112018" 
"${text[0..1]}.${text[2..3]}.${text[4..7]}"
```

However, it was not an "answer" in the SO way, so I'm accepting the answer by @tim_yates (also works and is probably a more precise and robust solution).

Comment: I need a way to do the opposite: 22112018 -> 22.11.2018.

Comment: Oops, sorry, misunderstood. You can just substring: `text = "22112018"` and `"${text[0..1]}.${text[2..3]}.${text[4..7]}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this is a date...

You could do:

```
Date.parse('ddMMyyyy', '22112018').format('dd.MM.yyyy')
```

instead of just grabbing characters